# How to create different columns in table view?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to have a table view set up but I'd like to have different columns as well. I want to have 3 pictures set across one row and when the user presses on one of the images the image gets passed to the next view controller. I have the passing of the image fine it's just that I don't know how to go through doing what I want to do.

I have my images set up in a 2D array that I use like this:

```
cell.image1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:_imagesToDisplay[row][0]];
cell.image2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:_imagesToDisplay[row][1]];
cell.image3.image = [UIImage imageNamed:_imagesToDisplay[row][2]];
```

[image: End Result]

This is how I have the image views set up at the moment but that's what I'm going for. Any help? Sorry, I'm very new to objective-C.

Answer (score 2):

Go through UICollectionView for this purpose.

Comment: Ditch the table view? I'm guessing you can make the collection view scrollable as well

Answer (score 1):

[`UICollectionView` is what you want](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html&ei=m1r2UrNd4arIAfXygfgJ&usg=AFQjCNFk-2JKlnvkEGh-a8qESnvdFu2obg&sig2=eUPSVWA7KzFTQ5nUIBmdvw&bvm=bv.60983673,d.aWc).  `UITableView` is 100% wrong for this.